# how to create socket.io multicast groups

Tags: node.js, multicast, socket.io

I want to emulate multicast with socket.io

I am used to BSD sockets where you save file descriptors in FD_SET, and iterate over them in an event loop to send() or write to them individually. If I can do the analogy in javascript, I will be golden:)

Any ideas on how to store the "file descriptors" and then individually send() data to those descriptors with socket.io?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas on how to store the "file
>   descriptors" and then individually
>   send() data to those descriptors with
>   socket.io?

You could store the socket.io id and use that to send messages to individual connections.

```
// v0.6.x
var sid = socket.sessionId;

// v0.7.x
var sid = socket.id;
```

You could push them onto an array on connection and remove from array on disconnection(or use redis for that).

---

But then again I think most times you are probably better of using namespace or rooms which you can read more information about on:

- http://socket.io/#how-to-use
- https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki

Comment: if I use rooms, does socket.io automatically clean up empty rooms from memory? I am dynamically generating rooms which works well. Thanks again.

Comment: thanks for the help. I posted another question I think you'd know off of the top : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631501/how-to-list-rooms-on-socket-io-nodejs-server