# how to list rooms on socket.io nodejs server

Tags: node.js, multicast, socket.io

after progress on the question [how to create socket.io multicast groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616922/how-to-create-socket-io-multicast-groups/6624604#6624604), I found making rooms a great way to do what I needed.

However, it would be great to know about all the rooms, without an extra data-structure.

Is it possible to get a list of all rooms on the server from the server socket?

Comment: Oops missed this answer completely, but hopefully my answer below can help you.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The short answer:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms
```

I analysed `io`:

I got the following output:

```
{ server: 
   { stack: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     connections: 3,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     watcher: { host: [Circular], callback: [Function] },
     _events: 
      { request: [Function],
        connection: [Function: connectionListener],
        listening: [Object],
        upgrade: [Object] },
     httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
     cache: {},
     settings: { home: '/', env: 'development', hints: true },
     redirects: {},
     isCallbacks: {},
     _locals: { settings: [Object], app: [Circular] },
     dynamicViewHelpers: {},
     errorHandlers: [],
     route: '/',
     routes: 
      { app: [Circular],
        routes: [Object],
        params: {},
        _params: [],
        middleware: [Function] },
     router: [Getter],
     __usedRouter: true,
     type: 'tcp4',
     fd: 7 },
  namespaces: 
   { '': 
      { manager: [Circular],
        name: '',
        sockets: [Object],
        auth: false,
        flags: [Object],
        _events: [Object] } },
  sockets: 
   { manager: [Circular],
     name: '',
     sockets: { '210837319844898486': [Object] },
     auth: false,
     flags: { endpoint: '', exceptions: [] },
     _events: { connection: [Function] } },
  settings: 
   { origins: '*:*',
     log: true,
     store: 
      { options: undefined,
        clients: [Object],
        manager: [Circular] },
     logger: { colors: true, level: 1 },
     heartbeats: true,
     resource: '/socket.io',
     transports: 
      [ 'websocket',
        'htmlfile',
        'xhr-polling',
        'jsonp-polling' ],
     authorization: [Function],
     'log level': 1,
     'close timeout': 25,
     'heartbeat timeout': 15,
     'heartbeat interval': 20,
     'polling duration': 20,
     'flash policy server': true,
     'flash policy port': 843,
     'destroy upgrade': true,
     'browser client': true,
     'browser client minification': false,
     'browser client etag': false,
     'browser client handler': false,
     'client store expiration': 15 },
  handshaken: 
   { '210837319844898486': 
      { headers: [Object],
        address: [Object],
        time: 'Mon Jul 18 2011 00:53:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)',
        xdomain: false,
        secure: undefined,
        PHPSESSID: '7qo6cht3q0rskhfes4eesb2d05' } },
  connected: { '210837319844898486': true },
  open: { '210837319844898486': true },
  closed: {},
  closedA: [],
  rooms: 
   { '': [ '210837319844898486' ],
     '/public-alfred': [ '210837319844898486' ] },
  roomClients: { '210837319844898486': [ '': true, '/public-alfred': true ] },
  oldListeners: [ [Function] ],
  _events: 
   { 'set:origins': [Function],
     'set:flash policy port': [Function],
     'set:transports': [Function] } }
```

after joining room "public-alfred" from a single client `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` contained:

```
 { '': [ '210837319844898486' ],
         '/public-alfred': [ '210837319844898486' ] }
```

Comment: Or even simpler, `io.rooms` works as `io.sockets.manager` is a circular reference. They will give you the same thing, just `io.rooms` is less verbose.

Comment: I don't think this works with socket.io version 1.0.  Maybe? `io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms`

Comment: Alfred, i edited the answer for both API version, there are potential reader still using 9.x like me :)

Comment: simple `socket.rooms` does the trick nowadays.. gotta love progress ;)

Comment: Heads up: this is changing in socket.io 1.4.x

Comment: @Alfred, I am using version 1.4.x. How do I get the room names for each room within `io.sockets.adapters.rooms`? When I create a room and join, I do allot it a name like `socket.join('someRoom')`, but when I use `io.sockets.adapters.rooms`, I get a reference like `/#4Ps4Ql-bx2R3qFH6AAAC`. How do I get the corresponding name?

Comment: Can we update this answer for socket.io 3.x.x ? as this no longer works

Answer (score 20):

As everyone said, in a new version of socket.io (1.x) the rooms can be found at:

```
    io.sockets.adapter.rooms
```

This will return something like:

```
{ 
    'qNADgg3CCxESDLm5AAAA': [ 'qNADgg3CCxESDLm5AAAA': true ],
    'myRoom': [ 'qNADgg3CCxESDLm5AAAA': true,
                '0rCX3v4pufWvQ6uwAAAB': true,
                'iH0wJHGh-qKPRd2RAAAC': true ],  
    '0rCX3v4pufWvQ6uwAAAB': [ '0rCX3v4pufWvQ6uwAAAB': true ],  
    'iH0wJHGh-qKPRd2RAAAC': [ 'iH0wJHGh-qKPRd2RAAAC': true ] 
}
```

The only room that I want to get is 'myRoom', so I wrote the following function for doing that:

```
function findRooms() {
    var availableRooms = [];
    var rooms = io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
    if (rooms) {
        for (var room in rooms) {
            if (!rooms[room].hasOwnProperty(room)) {
                availableRooms.push(room);
            }
        }
    }
    return availableRooms;
}
```

This was kind of confusing for me, hope this helps!

Comment: Your `findRooms()` function keeps returning all rooms to me as all items in that array have the property `room`. I'm on `socket.io v1.4.5`

Answer (score 17):

In a new version of socket.io (1.x), `io.sockets.manager.rooms` will cause an error. You should use `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` instead.

Comment: @slier: this is correct, only the first object is the default room - it looks like a random string -

Answer (score 6):

In socketIO version 2.2.0,

- `io.sockets.manager`  does not exist anymore

> **You can get all sockets in a specific room using followings 3.**
>
> socket.adapter.rooms;
> io.sockets.adapter.rooms
> io.sockets.adapter.sids

If you are using namespace you should use `socket.adapter.rooms`  to get the room lists.

```
{ '/userSocket#oXorUiql1GF68dbTAAAB':
   Room {
     sockets: { '/userSocket#oXorUiql1GF68dbTAAAB': true },
     length: 1 
     },
  roomOneName:
   Room {
     sockets: { '/userSocket#oXorUiql1GF68dbTAAAB': true },
     length: 1 
     },
  roomTwoName:
   Room {
     sockets: { '/userSocket#oXorUiql1GF68dbTAAAB': true },
     length: 1 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in case you are using

**socket.io 2.1.0**

and chanced upon this.

in 2.1.0, all the rooms in the server are located in the variable **io.sockets.adapter.rooms**

```
//Use Example//

sockets.on('getRooms', function() {
    sockets.emit('rooms', io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
});
```

You will get the following results.

> { xqfGuWYkKzT9hGgGAAAB: Room { sockets: { xqfGuWYkKzT9hGgGAAAB: true
>   }, length: 1 },   '0Ak9nTjme7bLsD8NAAAC': Room { sockets: {
>   '0Ak9nTjme7bLsD8NAAAC': true }, length: 1 } }

Answer (score 3):

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms)
```

use this to get all rooms.

Answer (score 2):

### If `io.sockets.adapter` is `undefined`..

I'm using *socket.io 1.7.1 (Server)*.

It seems `io.of("......").sockets.adapter` is `undefined` on that version of `socket.io`. So I used `io.adapter.rooms` instead and it works.

Comment: `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` works in Socket.IO 1.7.3.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [Socket.io-v3.x](https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/index.html#Disconnection), to get all current rooms created, you just simply do `socket.rooms`

```js
io.on('connection', socket => {

  console.log(socket.rooms);
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    // socket.rooms.size === 0
  });
});
```

and it return like this

```js
Set(2) {
  '_y_xQeeF6PpFiPQqAAFC',
  '6113cb71359644408895afcf6112df3c76981e3f88bc5c08'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find them using socket._events on an open connection.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('ping', function(data){
    console.log(socket._events);
  });
});
```

Output:

```
{
  ping: [Function],
  disconnect: [Function]
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP asked how to find rooms. This would be events. Still helpful on certain occasions but just not related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

in Socketio 2.0

to get rooms use

```
Object.keys(socket.adapter.rooms);
```

to get the room name

```
Object.keys(socket.adapter.rooms)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering out the 'real' rooms can be done like this:

```
var realRooms = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms).reduce((filtered, key) => {
    if(!io.sockets.adapter.rooms[key].sockets.hasOwnProperty(key)) filtered.push(key);
    return filtered;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

on v4 proceed like this:

```
Array.from(io.adapter.rooms.entries())
```

It will return an array with the keys (roomIds) and values (socketIds), same structure as Object.entries():

```
[
  [roomId],[Set(2) {"socketId1","socketId2"}],
  [roomId2], [Set(3) {"socketId3","socketId4","socketId5"}],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain an array of strings that contains all rooms in v4 you can use:

```
// if you are not using namespaces
Array.from(io.of("/").adapter.rooms.keys());
// if you are using namespaces
Array.from(io.of("/your-namespace").adapter.rooms.keys());
// output: ["room1", "room2", ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post my comment to the original question, but in addition, if you want to list all the rooms in a namespace, it should be coded like this:

```
var nsp = io.of('/my-nsp');

var rooms = nsp.adapter.rooms;
```

This would help so that if a client join a room by:

```
socket.join('my-room');
```

You should be able to see your room name when you do `console.log(rooms);`

I just want to answer an unanswered comment above as I ran into the same issue after I saw mismatched room names.

Comment: for me : `io.socket.of('').adapter.rooms[room]`

Answer (score 0):

```
function ActiveRooms(){
        var activeRooms = [];
        Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms).forEach(room=>{
            var isRoom = true;
            Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.sids).forEach(id=>{
                isRoom = (id === room)? false: isRoom;
            });
            if(isRoom)activeRooms.push(room);
        });
        return activeRooms;}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this is what I did. I noticed the ids are in the rooms for each socket.

Answer (score 0):

For socket v4. This works:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get("id of the room")
```

Answer (score -1):

You do it like this:

```js
await io.in(roomID).fetchSockets()
```