# List of namespaces in socket.io

Tags: socket.io

Is there any way to get a list of all the namespaces registered on the socket?

For example, suppose some client connects to a namespace: `socket = io('/some-nsp');

They are now in a namespace automagically because the socket.io does not prevent creating random namespaces.

If I want to go through the list of all existing namespaces and disconnect those users, how could I get such a list.

I've tried `io.nsps`, but this just is a circular list of junk.

Is there an "official" way to get a list of all the namespaces registered on the socket?  I don't want a list of clients.  I just want a list of namespaces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631501/how-to-list-rooms-on-socket-io-nodejs-server - is it applicable? I've been using Socket.io some time ago but AFAIR, rooms = namespaces.

Comment: Rooms and names spaces are very different creatures.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930286/socket-io-rooms-or-namespacing

Comment: What about `Object.keys(io.nsps)` ?

Comment: @CuriousGuy : Excellent.  That's what I needed.  Why don't you answer the question so I can vote it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Object.keys(io.nsps);
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, I found out namespaces are not global, so if you initialize another io object, the nsps property will not have your namespaces. Just something I ran into, FYI

Answer (score 4):

In v3 nsps is a map not an object. Try this:

```
io._nsps.keys()
```