# Array of rooms present on socket.io in v1.0

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chatroom

I have searched for it in stack overflow, but could not get what I wanted certainly. So here my question is: Is it possible to get an array of rooms presently available in socket.io.

I have looked other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631501/how-to-list-rooms-on-socket-io-nodejs-server) in stackoverflow. BUt I am not clear.

when I use `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` and console log the output, I get:

```
    { TeMJp5CVxdJlXsDiAAAA: [ TeMJp5CVxdJlXsDiAAAA: true ],
      lobby: [ TeMJp5CVxdJlXsDiAAAA: true ],
      'H-xHQXha_NdOs6sPAAAB': [ 'H-xHQXha_NdOs6sPAAAB': true ],
      room: [ 'H-xHQXha_NdOs6sPAAAB': true ],
     '5LglXlxtn498I9NaAAAC': [] }
```

It comprises of ids and room names mixed up. I need only array of rooms. Need help

Comment: The problem is every connected socket joins a "default" room with the socket id as name.
Maybe you can check `io.sockets.connected` for all connected socket ids and filter them out of the room list. But then you have the problem that rooms stay there even after disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way this guys deals with that problem so I give credit to his work instead. Basically whenever a room is created you add it to an array. https://github.com/tamaspiros/advanced-chat