# socket.io getting list of sockets that have joined a certain room

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using version 2.3.0, and I want to get a list of socket objects that have joined a certain room. Now I know that there have been many similar questions in the past, and from what I've gathered, the following code can be used to obtain a list of the socket id's in a given room (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
io.of('/').in('room_name').clients((error, clients) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  // Returns an array of client IDs like ["Anw2LatarvGVVXEIAAAD"]
  console.log(clients); 
});
```

From these client IDs, it looks like I can get the actual socket objects by using `io.of('/').in('room_name').connected[id]`?

What I don't understand is, what does `io.of('/').in('room_name').connected` actually contain? The [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-connected) does not make it super clear, as it seems to suggest that it is a map of the socket objects connected to that room. However, if this were the case, couldn't I simply get the list of socket objects like so:

```
const sockets = Object.values(io.of('/').in('room_name').connected)
```

There have been many questions on this in the past (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532196/get-list-of-clients-in-a-socket-io-room-2-0)), and none of them seem to mention this. Does `connected` not actually contain what I think it does? Or is this only relevant when you are using multiple Socket.IO nodes?

Comment: I tested this code and it seems to work...What is the problem exactly? Maybe you're using an older version?

Comment: @i.brod I wasn't saying it doesn't work, I was just wondering why have two separate API's for the same thing? Unless they are not actually the same?

Comment: It's possible that different api's exist for backwards compatibility i guess..Socketio seems to have changed a lot, during the years. You can see so many "Edit February 2019:" sections in the various posts about these issues.