# How to check if a socket exist in socket.io

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

Is possible in socket.io to check if a romm exist when an user try to join it? I want to show a 404 page using vue-router but I'm not sure if the `io.sockets` object will contain all the sockets that are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can check if a room exists.  All the rooms exist in the io object at this location: `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`.  If you look there you will see all rooms listed out with all the users in each room and the number of users.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6727354/11755375) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will implement this into my code.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!