# Where is io.sockets.adapter.rooms in io of nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, io

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6727354/462608

> The short answer:
> io.sockets.adapter.rooms
>
> I analysed io:

The sockets output part from io as shown in that answer contains the following:

```
sockets: 
   { manager: [Circular],
     name: '',
     sockets: { '210837319844898486': [Object] },
     auth: false,
     flags: { endpoint: '', exceptions: [] },
     _events: { connection: [Function] } },
```

Where is the `adapter`? Where are the `rooms`?

What is the way to find out adapter and rooms from the output of `io`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to get room before joining it. First You have to Join room and than you can get the rooms in `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` You can checkout this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_rooms.htm) to know rooms

```
let room_id = 111

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
    // Everytime a client logs in, display a connected message
    console.log("Server-Client Connected!");
    socket.join("_room" + room_id);
    socket.on('connected', function (data) {

    });
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
    socket.on('qr_code_scan', function (room_id) {
        io.sockets.in("_room" + room_id).emit("qr_code_scan", true);
    });
});
```

Log of `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`

```
{bjYiUV5YZy54VedKAAAA: Room, _room111: Room}
app.js:55
_room111:Room {sockets: {…}, length: 1}
length:1
sockets:{-isBAZIB-Sm3jArgAAAB: true}
-isBAZIB-Sm3jArgAAAB:true
__proto__:Object
__proto__:Object
-isBAZIB-Sm3jArgAAAB:Room {sockets: {…}, length: 1}
length:1
sockets:{-isBAZIB-Sm3jArgAAAB: true}
-isBAZIB-Sm3jArgAAAB:true
__proto__:Object
__proto__:Object
__proto__:Object
```

Answer (score 2):

For the current version of "socket.io": "^4.1.2",

> io.sockets.adapter.rooms

is a Map like this:

> Map(2) {   'hgdAp3ghn1RQZk3iAAAD' => Set(1) { 'hgdAp3ghn1RQZk3iAAAD'
> },   'test' => Set(1) { 'hgdAp3ghn1RQZk3iAAAD' } }

when a room already exist, in this case 'test'.

If you invoke it before a room has been created, then it'd be:

Map(1) { 'w2e2Vnav-zmf6pm4AAAD' => Set(1) { 'w2e2Vnav-zmf6pm4AAAD' } }

Thus the long answer is that it depends on the version you are using, and that for version 4.x the room will only be part of the map after an user has joined the room, not before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's up with that response. But I can confirm that when I run a basic socket.io example ([codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nodejs-socketio-tic-tac-toe-forked-jtmpb?file=/server/index.js)) using socket.io@2.1.1 and console.log(io) I see the following in my terminal:

```
Server {
  nsps: {
    '/': Namespace {
      name: '/',
      server: [Circular],
      sockets: [Object],
      connected: [Object],
      fns: [],
      ids: 0,
      rooms: [],
      flags: {},
      adapter: [Adapter],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1
    }
  },
  parentNsps: Map {},
  _path: '/socket.io',
  _serveClient: true,
  parser: {
    protocol: 4,
    types: [
      'CONNECT',
      'DISCONNECT',
      'EVENT',
      'ACK',
      'ERROR',
      'BINARY_EVENT',
      'BINARY_ACK'
    ],
    CONNECT: 0,
    DISCONNECT: 1,
    EVENT: 2,
    ACK: 3,
    ERROR: 4,
    BINARY_EVENT: 5,
    BINARY_ACK: 6,
    Encoder: [Function: Encoder],
    Decoder: [Function: Decoder]
  },
  encoder: Encoder {},
  _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
  _origins: '*:*',
  sockets: Namespace {
    name: '/',
    server: [Circular],
    sockets: { WFrro9MpS4d1nSouAAAA: [Socket] },
    connected: { WFrro9MpS4d1nSouAAAA: [Socket] },
    fns: [],
    ids: 0,
    rooms: [],
    flags: {},
    adapter: Adapter {
      nsp: [Circular],
      rooms: [Object],
      sids: [Object],
      encoder: Encoder {}
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { connection: [Array] },
    _eventsCount: 1
  },
  eio: Server {
    clients: { WFrro9MpS4d1nSouAAAA: [Socket] },
    clientsCount: 1,
    wsEngine: 'ws',
    pingTimeout: 5000,
    pingInterval: 25000,
    upgradeTimeout: 10000,
    maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
    transports: [ 'polling', 'websocket' ],
    allowUpgrades: true,
    allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
    cookie: 'io',
    cookiePath: '/',
    cookieHttpOnly: true,
    perMessageDeflate: { threshold: 1024 },
    httpCompression: { threshold: 1024 },
    initialPacket: [ '0' ],
    ws: WebSocketServer {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      options: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { connection: [Function: bound ] },
    _eventsCount: 1
  },
  httpServer: Server {
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      connection: [Function: connectionListener],
      close: [Function: bound ],
      listening: [Function: bound ],
      upgrade: [Function],
      request: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 5,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _connections: 2,
    _handle: TCP {
      reading: false,
      onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular]
    },
    _usingWorkers: false,
    _workers: [],
    _unref: false,
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    pauseOnConnect: false,
    httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
    timeout: 120000,
    keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    headersTimeout: 60000,
    _connectionKey: '6::::8080',
    [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
    [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6
  },
  engine: Server {
    clients: { WFrro9MpS4d1nSouAAAA: [Socket] },
    clientsCount: 1,
    wsEngine: 'ws',
    pingTimeout: 5000,
    pingInterval: 25000,
    upgradeTimeout: 10000,
    maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
    transports: [ 'polling', 'websocket' ],
    allowUpgrades: true,
    allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
    cookie: 'io',
    cookiePath: '/',
    cookieHttpOnly: true,
    perMessageDeflate: { threshold: 1024 },
    httpCompression: { threshold: 1024 },
    initialPacket: [ '0' ],
    ws: WebSocketServer {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      options: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { connection: [Function: bound ] },
    _eventsCount: 1
  }
}
```

With the rooms in `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`.