# How to get all active rooms with socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to get a list off all active Rooms from the server. I've tried everything from this link: [how to list rooms on socket.io nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631501/how-to-list-rooms-on-socket-io-nodejs-server)

But nothing seems to work.

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
let numberOfRooms = 0;
let listOfRooms = [];
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  //   listOfRooms = [io.adapter.rooms.entries()];
  console.log(io.adapter.rooms);
  //   console.log(listOfRooms);

  // console.log(socket.adapter.rooms);
  socket.on("joinRoom", (roomName) => {
    socket.join(roomName);
    console.log("this is room", roomName);
    // socket.emit("getRooms", socket.rooms);
  });

  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    //socket.broadcast.emit("message_received", data);
    io.to(data.to).emit("message_received", data);
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected", socket.id);
  });
```

Has anyone an idea how to return all the active rooms from the Server?